# Почему mysql запрос отдает None?

Tags: python, mysql

```
    def insertValue(self):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO clans (id, name, memberPlayers, normal_points) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        list = ('', 'Аффинаж', "qwe", 100)
        a = cursor.execute(sql , list )
        print(a)
```

В бд ничего не записывается 
Но вывод данных из бд работает, в чем беда?

Comment: А что он должен быть, по-вашему, вернуть? запрос на вставку данных ничего не возвращает, это не выборка.

Comment: Если в функции нет явно написанного return "что-то", то функция возвращает None.

Comment: Смысл вопроса в том что не записывает, я по пхп привык что sql возвращает true или false, думал тут так же.

Comment: *не записывает* 1) Включите обработку ошибок и убедитесь, что cursor.execute не приводит к ошибке. А если приводит - процитируйте текст сообщения. 2) Включите на сервере General Log и смотрите точный текст запроса, поступившего на сервер.

Comment: коммит нужен после выполнения

Comment: @Akina вы так думаете? а `number of affected` rows как же?

Comment: вообще, нужно бы все обернуть в try-except и with

Comment: @strawdog не подскажите как это должно выглядить? Я пробовал, но ничего не получилось.

Comment: @Akina Что за обработчик?

Comment: @strawdog [Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) почему-то считает `cursor.execute` методом, а ни разу не свойством... так что оно как бы и не должно ничего возвращать. А `affected rows` и прочую ерунду надо бы оттуда фетчить отдельным методом, а потом получать через соотв. свойство. И та же документация про то, что именно возвращает данный метод, говорит приблизительно вообще ничего...

Comment: *Что за обработчик?* Вы "по пхп привыкли" писать `or die`? вот и тут напишите то же самое, но в соответствии с синтаксисом питона.

Comment: @Akina, ошибок никаких.

Comment: У меня тут возник диссонанс:
Я сделал запрос 
a = db.getValues("SELECT * FROM clans") 
print(a)

Он мне выдал 2 записи, одна из них та что я записывал через py, хотя в phpmyadmin отображается только одна...

Comment: `autocommit=true`. Или явно фиксируйте транзакции.

Comment: @Akina мы, вероятно, разную документацию читаем... по вашей же ссылке приведен пример с возвращенными значениями в cursor.execute. да и в документации по pymysql английским по белому написано, что "Returns: Number of affected rows".

Comment: @strawdog *по вашей же ссылке приведен пример с возвращенными значениями в cursor.execute* ... и почти сразу же явно написано *execute() returns an iterator if `multi` is True.* Чего я в коде автора в упор не вижу. *мы, вероятно, разную документацию читаем...* А вот это запросто.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала сделайте так, чтобы ваш код отлавливал исключения, так как это описано в  [документации](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html):

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

И уже потом начинайте анализировать ошибки и исключения.

Comment: У автора вопроса нет никаких исключений, отлавливать нечего